# Updating parent form from child using Radio

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a form with 11 multiple choice questions.

Ive created a statefull widget which takes the question and displays this along with 3 radio buttons as below.

Each question needs to update different property in a model defined within the parent widget.

for example:

```
RadioQuestionWidget("What colour is the sky?", model.ColourOfSky),
RadioQuestionWidget("What colour is the grass?", model.ColourOfGrass)
```

Below is my RadioQuestionWidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RadioQuestionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RadioQuestionWidget({Key key, this.question}) : super(key: key);
  final String question;

  @override
  _RadioQuestionWidgetState createState() => _RadioQuestionWidgetState();
}

class _RadioQuestionWidgetState extends State<RadioQuestionWidget> {
  String question;
  var _radioValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    question = widget.question;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            question,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Radio(
                  value: "Yes",
                  groupValue: _radioValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _radioValue = val;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Yes',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: "No",
                  groupValue: _radioValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _radioValue = val;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'No',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: "Three",
                  groupValue: _radioValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _radioValue = val;
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.red,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Not applicable',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, define one function in your parent widget with required arguments i.e your question number and answer.

```
void _updateProperty(int que_num, String ans) {
    //update property according to your question number and ans
}
```

Now pass your function to child widget as the Constructor argument.

```
RadioQuestionWidget(question : "What colour is the sky?", updatePropertyHandler : _updateProperty)
```

Receive your function in child widget like below.

```
class RadioQuestionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RadioQuestionWidget({Key key, this.question, this.updatePropertyHandler}) : super(key: key);
  final String question;
  final Function updatePropertyHandler;

  @override
  _RadioQuestionWidgetState createState() => _RadioQuestionWidgetState();
}
```

Now in your child widget while you answering the question, call _updateUi function as per your need.

```
Radio(
      value: "Yes",
      groupValue: _radioValue,
      onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
                _radioValue = val;
                //here questionNum is int value you need to handle question no
                widget.updatePropertyHandler(questionNum, _radioValue);
            });
      },
         activeColor: Colors.green,
         focusColor: Colors.black,
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please mark the above answer as the correct one as i couldn't have got it working  without the help of @Alpesh.

I had to slightly amend the answer in order to update the correct property of the model.

This in my parent widget:

```
            RadioQuestionWidget(
              question: 'Question 1',
              updatePropertyHandler: (String ans) => {
                setState(() {
                  _qc.speedForSpeedChaeckCompleted = ans;
                })
              },
            ),
```

and this is my RadioQuestionWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RadioQuestionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RadioQuestionWidget({Key key, this.question, this.updatePropertyHandler})
      : super(key: key);
  final String question;
  final Function updatePropertyHandler;

  @override
  _RadioQuestionWidgetState createState() => _RadioQuestionWidgetState();
}

class _RadioQuestionWidgetState extends State<RadioQuestionWidget> {
  String question;
  var _groupValue;
  Function(String) onCountChange;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    question = widget.question;
    _groupValue = 'Not Applicable';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            question,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Radio(
                  value: "Yes",
                  groupValue: _groupValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _groupValue = val;
                      //here questionNum is int value you need to handle question no
                      widget.updatePropertyHandler(val);
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Yes',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: "No",
                  groupValue: _groupValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _groupValue = val;
                      //here questionNum is int value you need to handle question no
                      widget.updatePropertyHandler(val);
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'No',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Radio(
                  value: "Not Applicable",
                  groupValue: _groupValue,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _groupValue = val;
                      //here questionNum is int value you need to handle question no
                      widget.updatePropertyHandler(val);
                    });
                  },
                  activeColor: Colors.red,
                  focusColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                new Text(
                  'Not applicable',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```